# see if some facebook app checks your IP

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-apps

i would like to know if there is a way to know if some facebook app is cheking all the users IP that enter in that app.

for example there is a page:
 https://www.facebook.com/RadioPopular.PrecosdeAmigo
and they have an app and when i enter for the first time in it, that when appears that windows where it asks for the acces to my likes, friend list, etc, then the link changes to the following: 
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=629628910413752&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wiseversion.pt%2Frp2013%2F&state=d7abf841cf54aa2f809de4eab686b1c2&sdk=php-sdk-3.2.2&scope=email%2Cuser_likes%2Cfriends_likes%2Cuser_photos

so i suspect that they are cheking my IP, but i am not sure. so i would like to know if there is a way to see if they are cheking my IP. by the way, are there other ways to see if some facebook app is cheking my IP?

i thank you in advance for the help

Comment: an easy way to test is try login again with a proxy (a foreign one, say if you are in the US, try a UK one) and see if they redirect you to another page

Comment: how do i login with a foreign proxy and by "see if they redirect you to another page" u mean other link?   that if with the proxy from US i get this link https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=629628910413752&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wiseversion.pt%2Frp2013%2F&state=d7abf841cf54aa2f809de4eab686b1c2&sdk=php-sdk-3.2.2&scope=email%2Cuser_likes%2Cfriends_likes%2Cuser_photos   then with the foreign proxy i will get some other link?

Comment: you can setup a proxy in your browser. if you have no idea what I'm talking about, read this first:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server

Answer (score 2):

Any server that you are communicating with has the capacity to see who it is talking to. When you request any resource from a server (via a browser in this case), there are some details attached to that request with information about the client that made the request and the actual request.

This will include things like your user agent (what type of browser you are using), the date/time of the request and also information about the request. You can see a list of possible fields that are sent on [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields). The details that are sent are called headers and are not necessarily related or connected to the actual request (what you are asking for).

You can be sure that your IP address is being monitored at some level. Even if it's within the server's log files. This does not mean that the application is using this information. In the case of an IP address, the data can easily be manipulated - by a proxy for example.

---

To answer your question - **there is no sure way to know if the application is monitoring your IP address.**

The behavior you are seeing is that of an authentication process. Only if permissions need to be requested you will be prompted with the login dialog. Once you have authenticated the application, there is no need to request more permissions since you have already granted them.

You'll notice, if you do exactly the same thing but the second time you enter the application you use a different IP address (from a different computer), the process is the same. Each Facebook user will only ever see that login dialog once (unless they uninstall the application).

Answer (score 1):

They are asking permissions from your Facebook account. The second URL you supplied is the URL that sets that you have accepted the permissions so they can be saved so you do not need to accept them every time you visit the app.

They might be getting your IP but I dont think there is a way to tell. The main thing that us being checked is if you are logged in and if you have already accepted the permission.

Hope this helps.

Comment: so u say that they are not able to check my IP? i have accepted that things that ask to see my info, but inside the app they are already able to see my IP. so i want to know if they are cheking my IP.

Comment: Yes they can see your IP my point was that there is no way to check if they are doing anything with your IP. What do you think they are checking with your IP?